# Plank doesn't change the icon according to the system

Tags: arch-linux, docker, icons, kde5, plank

I install Arch with KDE Plasma, and I use Plank as my dock. When I change the default icon in the system with Numix square icon, plank doesn't change but keep the default icon.

It's better described in this screenshot, and note that the deadbeef icon in toolbar is also the default icon.

[image]

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plank is based on GTK3, KDE isn't. So you have to go to **System Settings** / **Application Style** / **GNOME Application Style** and there you can change in selectbar **Icon theme**, which you like.

[image: System settings]

Plank will use icon set, which you choose.

[image: Plank]

Mentioned [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/plank/+question/258486).